# optimizing 3 variable function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, visualization

I have the following function:

`m = f(x,y,z) = (a * (1 + x/100) * b - d * (1 + y/100)) / (h * (1 + z/100))`
where a, d, h, b are positive constants and the variables are x,z,y (positive too)

My question is: how can I find for given `x` (between 1 and 1000), the optimal `y,z` so that `m` is as low as possible?

It seems that for different values x, some times y is more "important" (in lowering m) and others z is more important. I also don't have a clue how to visualize this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The objective is unbounded from below: if $y\to\infty$ then $m\to-\infty$. The minimization makes no sense as stated unless you put an explicit restriction on $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0):

if a,d, h,b are positive and x,y,z are also positive and m is not constrained than you need to make (a * (1 + x/100) * b as small as possible meaning x should be very neare to zero...
and you need to try to make d * (1 + y/100)) / (h * (1 + z/100)) as large as possible..meaning y/z should be as large as it could be...y/z  goes to infinity
a*(1+0)- infinity
your answer should be infinite...

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for my not clear initial post. x is always a big value, bigger than 1. x can take values from 1 to 1000, so for each of these values i'm looking to minimize it by adjusting y and z

Comment: if variables are constrained ie x is between 1 and 1000 etc... then this is non linear programming question. you could google and come up to one of the calculators such as     https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=895957d708a52242400f57757f81e627